# Moving Display:Block link text to the bottom of a div

Tags: css, html, positioning, blocking

So I have this Div that has a roll over effect on it where it changes the border color on roll over, in order to make this div a link I've put a link into the DIV and given it a Display: Block property so it fills the div.

What I'm having an incredibly hard time doing is getting the text to align to the bottom left corner of this div while keeping the blocking so the whole roll over area stays a link.

ANY solutions to this problem I'd greatly appreciate, thanks for your help in advance I've been battling this for a while.

http://www.klossal.com/media/index_test.html

this is the test page and this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"      
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head> 
 <title>MEDIA</title> 
</head> 

<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
function mouseover() 
{ 
document.getElementById("thediv").style.borderLeft="10px solid black";  
} 
function mouseout() 
{ 
document.getElementById("thediv").style.borderLeft="10px solid #898787";
}

//--> 
</SCRIPT>
<style type="text/css"> 

</style>

</HEAD> 
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="\favicon.ico"> 


<body> 

<DIV style="width:200px;height:200px;border-left:10px solid #898787" id=thediv     
onmouseover="mouseover()" onmouseout="mouseout()">
<a style="padding-top:1cmpx;" href="www.klossal.com">LINK IT BABY</a>
<DIV>

</body> 
</html> 

</body>
```

Comment: not sure if I understood u, but if u just want to move to link text Link it Baby down, you can use position absolute and top:150px;(say)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align something to the bottom, one can set the `position` to `absolute` and `bottom` to `0px`. This will align it to bottom of the first parent that is positioned either absolute or relative.

In your case, set the `position` of the `DIV` to `relative`, the `position` of the link to `absolute` and the `bottom` of the link to `0px`:

http://jsfiddle.net/rodin/jxyZz/

And by the way, you can achieve the rollover effect with pure CSS, see the fiddle. If you want to make the entire box a link, the box should be an `A` and the text a `DIV` (you did it the other way around).

Comment: this works incredibly well, the only problem is when I change the text styling on jsfiddle it works, but for some reason when I then move it to my site the exact same way it starts off in the hover stlye, and as soon as I roll over it it functions normally.

Comment: http://www.klossal.com/media/index_new.html  that's the site, this is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rodin/jxyZz/

Comment: so I positioned it with a UL and LI and when it's in the organized list it works fine, weird.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an additional span element that will positioned a the bottom of the link. Note you could create the hover effect in css as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Te23c/

**Html**

text

```
a{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    position: relative
}
```

**CSS**

```
a:hover{
    background: lime
}

span{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
}
```